# enum vs typeId in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, orm, enums, mapping, hibernate-mapping

I'm implementing a database table like the following:

```
Do_Something
------------
Id
Name
Frequency
```

Frequency can only be 1 of 3 values *at the moment*; immediate, daily or weekly.  So I can implement the Frequency field as a `String`, in which case the hibernate mapping would be a simple easy `enum`.  However, as easy as the code implementation is, it seems ugly and inefficient on the database side with hundreds of thousands of `String`s.  So maybe I had a frequency table:

```
Frequency
---------
Id
Value
```

And now I have the Do_Something.Frequency field as a foreign key to this table.  Now I have to hardcode the preset frequencyIds in my code to make querying the Do_Something table easier to deal with.  I'm not sure how much use the Frequency table will have aside from within the Do_Something table.  Maybe in the future other tables will make use of it...

So the question is, do I make frequency a simple `enum` in code and in the db as a `String`, or make frequency an `enum` in code that gets translated to and from a frequency_id in the db or make frequency constants in code that match the various possible frequency ids in the db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it boils down to whether you want to keep `Frequency` normalized or not. There is a lot written about it but my take is that unless you expect regular changes in values of Frequency, there is not much need for complexity of extra table.

I would consider enum with some additional display name and well established string names. That would give you a chance to rename presentation name if needed without changing database.
For example:

```
IMMEDIATE("Immediate"),
DAILY("Daily"),
WEEKLY("Weekly")
```

Drawback is that if you ever decide to change those enum values you will have to migrate database. But from practical standpoint, why would you ever want to rename them?